# The volume of null-set

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration

I saw this claim:

> if $v(E)$ = 0, then E is a null-set. The converse
>   statement is wrong.

where $v(E)$ is the Jordan measure of $E$,

I am not sure if this right, because I know $\int_E1_E=0 $ for $E$ null set and for any bounded function.

Comment: What is the definition of null-set? A set of zero Lebesgue measure?

Comment: What exactly is a null-set in this context? It might be defined as a set $N$ that is a subset of a measurable set $A$ with $\nu(A)=0$ (or perhaps $\lambda(A)=0$ as @Daniel suggests). The expression $\nu(E)=0$ only makes sense if $E$ is measurable, but if $\nu$ is not a complete measure then there are also null-sets that are *not* measurable. That's why the converse is wrong.

Comment: The set E $\subset R^n$ is a null-set if for each $\epsilon$ > 0 there exist open bricks $Q_j$ such that E $\subset \cup_j Q_j$ and $\sum_j v(Q_j )$ < $\epsilon$

Comment: just for being sure $[0,1]\cap \Bbb{Q} $ is a null set and not measurable right?

Comment: @shay: That set is Lebesgue measurable, but not Jordan measurable. Its closure is [0, 1], its interior empty. And these don't have the same measure in $\mathbb{R}$.